# Need to fill the non zero values in my sales column until non zero value appears with reference to a value in another column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, fill, zero

Say I have 4 columns, id,brand, flag and sales:
For each unique combination of id and brand, where flag == 1, I move to corresponding row in sales column(say here sales value is x and following rows have value 0) and start to look at the following rows until a non-zero value appears. Need to fill these zero cells along with the value x with a number which is equal to (value(x)/number of zeroes following x+1)

```
Flag  Sales
0   4
1   15
0   0
0   0
0   2
0  0
1 10
0  0
0  3
0  0
```

output should be:

```
Flag  Sales
0   4
1   5
0   5
0   5
0   2
0  0
1  5
0  5
0  3
```

Comment: Not totally clear to me from your description, but `ave(dat$Sales, cumsum(rowSums(dat > 0) > 0))` returns the desired result for your example.

Comment: @lmo your answer is way better than existing answers for the dupe. Consider posting.

Comment: Thanks @Masoud It's been posted there.

Comment: I believe, I posted an unclear question last time. Kindly look at the problem at hand once again.